# Deploy gulp project to azurewebsites

Tags: angularjs, azure, ftp, gulp

My project looks something like this:

├── bower.json

├── src

│   ├── bower_components

│   ├── images

│   ├── index.html

│   ├── scripts.min.js

│   └── styles.min.css

├── gulpfile.js

├── index.html

├── node_modules

│   ├── gulp-module-1

│   └── gulp-module-2

├── package.json

└── README

And I build it on localhost by 'gulp serve'. How can I host in on ftp server (azurewebsites)? What to upload?

Comment: I am guessing if your `gulp serve` is doing more than just compiling scripts but also starting a web server? If so, you shouldn't use this and you should set the output directory (e.g. `dist/`) as the root directory. Could you also post your `gulpfile.js` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please look at the comment first! Below answer is just for the case that your `gulp serve` is used for compiling script only. If your gulp is starting a web server, you need not to try below.**

---

Azure Web App (aka Azure Web Sites) is backed by [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/).

You may set up a custom deployment script in Kudu by adding a `.deployment` and `deployment.sh` to the root of your project. Every time when you push new commit to repository, Kudu will run your deployment script. (***Note***: FTP upload will not trigger deployment)

---

Sample `.deployment`:

```
[config]  
command = bash ./deploy.sh
```

---

Sample `deploy.sh` (*modified version from the blog post below*)

```
# Deployment  
# ----------  

echo Handling node.js gulp deployment.  

# 1. Select node version  
selectNodeVersion  

# 2. Install npm packages  
if [ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE/package.json" ]; then  
  eval $NPM_CMD install  
  exitWithMessageOnError "npm failed"  
fi  

# 3. Install bower packages  
if [ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE/bower.json" ]; then  
  eval $NPM_CMD install bower  
  exitWithMessageOnError "installing bower failed"  
  ./node_modules/.bin/bower install  
  exitWithMessageOnError "bower failed"  
fi  

# 4. Run gulp for build
if [ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE/gulpfile.js" ]; then  
  eval $NPM_CMD install gulp 
  exitWithMessageOnError "installing gulpfailed"  
  ./node_modules/.bin/gulp serve
  exitWithMessageOnError "gulp failed"  
fi  

# 5. KuduSync to Target  
"$KUDU_SYNC_CMD" -v 500 -f "$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE/dist" -t "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET" -n "$NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH" -p "$PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.sh"  
exitWithMessageOnError "Kudu Sync to Target failed"
```

---

Further reading:

[Git and Grunt Deploy to Windows Azure](http://www.cptloadtest.com/2013/12/03/Git-And-Grunt-Deploy-To-Windows-Azure.aspx)

[Custom Deployment Scripts For Microsoft Azure Web App (Website) Using Git Deployment](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/38417491924/azurewebsitecustomdeploymentpart1/#.VeumUBEViUk)