# Azure deployment issue Missing server.js/app.js files

Tags: node.js, azure, gulp, web-deployment, kudu

I am trying to deploy my code on Azure Web app

My package.json file is:

```
{
  "name": "blur_admin",
  "version": "1.3.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "~2.18.2",
    "browser-sync-spa": "~1.0.3",
    "chalk": "~1.1.1",
    "del": "~2.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-angular": "~0.12.0",
    "estraverse": "~4.2.0",
    "gulp": "~3.9.0",
    "gulp-angular-filesort": "~1.1.1",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "~2.0.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "~3.1.1",
    "gulp-eslint": "~1.0.0",
    "gulp-filter": "~4.0.0",
    "gulp-flatten": "~0.3.1",
    "gulp-gh-pages": "^0.5.4",
    "gulp-inject": "~4.1.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "~1.4.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "~1.2.1",
    "gulp-minify-html": "~1.0.4",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "~2.0.0",
    "gulp-prompt": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-protractor": "~3.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-replace": "~0.5.4",
    "gulp-rev": "~7.1.2",
    "gulp-rev-replace": "~0.4.2",
    "gulp-sass": "~2.3.2",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.5.2",
    "gulp-size": "~2.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "~1.6.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "~2.0.0",
    "gulp-useref": "~1.3.0",
    "gulp-util": "~3.0.6",
    "gulp-zip": "^3.0.2",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "~0.17.2",
    "lodash": "~4.17.2",
    "main-bower-files": "~2.13.1",
    "uglify-save-license": "~0.4.1",
    "wiredep": "~4.0.0",
    "wrench": "~1.5.8"
  },

  "engines": {
    "node": "6.11.2",
    "npm": "5.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1"
  }
}
```

and my deploy.cmd file is

```
@if "%SCM_TRACE_LEVEL%" NEQ "4" @echo off

:: ----------------------
:: KUDU Deployment Script
:: Version: 1.0.15
:: ----------------------

:: Prerequisites
:: -------------

:: Verify node.js installed
where node 2>nul >nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  echo Missing node.js executable, please install node.js, if already installed make sure it can be reached from current environment.
  goto error
)

:: Setup
:: -----

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET ARTIFACTS=%~dp0%..\artifacts

IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE (
  SET DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE=%~dp0%.
)

IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_TARGET (
  SET DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=%ARTIFACTS%\wwwroot
)

IF NOT DEFINED NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH (
  SET NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH=%ARTIFACTS%\manifest

  IF NOT DEFINED PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH (
    SET PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH=%ARTIFACTS%\manifest
  )
)

IF NOT DEFINED KUDU_SYNC_CMD (
  :: Install kudu sync
  echo Installing Kudu Sync
  call npm install kudusync -g --silent
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

  :: Locally just running "kuduSync" would also work
  SET KUDU_SYNC_CMD=%appdata%\npm\kuduSync.cmd
)
goto Deployment

:: Utility Functions
:: -----------------

:SelectNodeVersion

IF DEFINED KUDU_SELECT_NODE_VERSION_CMD (
  :: The following are done only on Windows Azure Websites environment
  call %KUDU_SELECT_NODE_VERSION_CMD% "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%" "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%"
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

  IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\__nodeVersion.tmp" (
    SET /p NODE_EXE=<"%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\__nodeVersion.tmp"
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  )

  IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\__npmVersion.tmp" (
    SET /p NPM_JS_PATH=<"%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\__npmVersion.tmp"
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  )

  IF NOT DEFINED NODE_EXE (
    SET NODE_EXE=node
  )

  SET NPM_CMD="!NODE_EXE!" "!NPM_JS_PATH!"
) ELSE (
  SET NPM_CMD=npm
  SET NODE_EXE=node
)

goto :EOF

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Deployment
:: ----------

:Deployment
echo Handling node.js deployment.

:: 1. Select node version
call :SelectNodeVersion

:: 2. Install npm packages
IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\package.json" (
  call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! install
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
)

:: 3. Execute Gulp
IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\gulpfile.js" (
    call .\node_modules\.bin\gulp serve:dist
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
)

:: 4. KuduSync
IF /I "%IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT%" NEQ "1" (
  call :ExecuteCmd "%KUDU_SYNC_CMD%" -v 50 -f "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\dist" -t "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" -n "%NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH%" -p "%PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH%" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd"
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
)

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
goto end

:: Execute command routine that will echo out when error
:ExecuteCmd
setlocal
set _CMD_=%*
call %_CMD_%
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" NEQ "0" echo Failed exitCode=%ERRORLEVEL%, command=%_CMD_%
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

:error
endlocal
echo An error has occurred during web site deployment.
call :exitSetErrorLevel
call :exitFromFunction 2>nul

:exitSetErrorLevel
exit /b 1

:exitFromFunction
()

:end
endlocal
echo Finished successfully.
```

> An error has occurred during web site deployment. A subdirectory or
>   file D:\home\site\repository\lib already exists.\r\nMissing
>   server.js/app.js files, web.config is not generated\r\nnpm WARN
>   lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\nodejs\6.9.1\node.exe but npm is using D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\nodejs\6.11.2\node.exe itself. Use the
>   `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node
>   binary npm was executed with.\r\nnpm WARN blur_admin@1.3.1 No
>   repository field.\r\nnpm WARN blur_admin@1.3.1 No license
>   field.\r\nnpm WARN The package lodash is included as both a dev and
>   production dependency.\r\n\r\nnpm WARN deprecated bower@1.8.2:
>   ...psst! Your project can stop working at any moment because its
>   dependencies can change. Prevent this by migrating to Yarn:
>   https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/\r\nnpm WARN
>   lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\nodejs\6.9.1\node.exe but npm is using D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\nodejs\6.11.2\node.exe itself. Use the
>   `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node
>   binary npm was executed with.\r\n'node_modules.bin\bower' is not
>   recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or
>   batch file.\r\n(node:11612) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
>   Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Error: jquery is
>   not installed. Try running `bower install` or remove the component
>   from your bower.json file.\r\nD:\Program Files
>   (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\67.61027.3099\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd
>   deploy.cmd

I am trying from days but unable to solve this issue, can anyone please help?
TIA

Answer (score 0):

The node.js version `6.11.2` you specified in the `package.json` is not supported on Azure App Service. You could change it to `6.9.5` or any other available one.

You can see all node.js versions supported by Azure at the URL `https://<yourappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/diagnostics/runtime`

Comment: Node.js versions available on the platform are: 0.10.21, 0.10.24, 0.10.26, 0.10.28, 0.10.29, 0.10.31, 0.10.32, 0.10.40, 0.12.0, 0.12.2, 0.12.3, 0.12.6, 4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.1.2, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3, 4.2.4, 4.3.0, 4.3.2, 4.4.0, 4.4.1, 4.4.6, 4.4.7, 4.5.0, 4.6.0, 4.6.1, 4.8.4, 5.0.0, 5.1.1, 5.3.0, 5.4.0, 5.5.0, 5.6.0, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.8.0, 5.9.1, 6.0.0, 6.1.0, 6.2.2, 6.3.0, 6.5.0, 6.6.0, 6.7.0, 6.9.0, 6.9.1, 6.9.2, 6.9.4, 6.9.5, 6.10.0, 6.10.3, 6.11.1, 6.11.2, 6.11.5, 7.0.0, 7.1.0, 7.2.0, 7.3.0, 7.4.0, 7.5.0, 7.6.0, 7.7.0, 7.7.4, 7.10.0, 7.10.1, 8.0.0, 8.1.4, 8.4.0, 8.5.0, 8.7.0, 8.8.0, 8.8.1, 8.9.0.

Comment: Well, have you run `bower install` command to install all bower components? The error indicates that jquery is not installed. And see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32410527/deploy-gulp-project-to-azurewebsites/32419556#32419556) to see if it helps.